# (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListFunctions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have created a lambda script to clean up old versions based on this useful page (https://vipmunot.medium.com/how-to-remove-older-versions-of-lambda-a4415f11a2da)

```
Description:
  Resources:
    LambdaFunctionRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - sts:AssumeRole
        Path: "/"
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: AWSLambdaFullAccess
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                  Resource: '*'

                  LambdaFunction:
                    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
                    Properties:
                      Runtime: python3.6
                      Timeout: 5
                      Handler: index.handler
                      Role: !GetAtt LambdaFunctionRole.Arn
                      Code:
                        ZipFile:
                          !Sub
                          - |-
                            #!/usr/bin/env python3

                            import json
                            import boto3
                            from collections import Counter
                            def lambda_handler(event, context):
                                client = boto3.client('lambda')
                                response = client.list_functions(FunctionVersion='ALL')
                                d = dict(Counter([x['FunctionName'] for x in response['Functions']]))
                                print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
                                for key, value in d.items():
                                    if value > 5:
                                       print(key, '->', value)
                                       a = {}
                                       for x in response['Functions']:
                                           if x['FunctionName'] == key and x['Version'] != '$LATEST':
                                               #print(x['FunctionArn'],x['LastModified'])
                                               a[x['FunctionArn']] = x['LastModified']
                                       listofTuples = sorted(a.items() , key=lambda x: x[1])
                                       print(a)
                                       print(json.dumps(listofTuples))
                                       if len(listofTuples) > 5:
                                           for elem in listofTuples[0:len(listofTuples)-5]:
                                               #response = client.delete_function(FunctionName=elem[0])
                                               print("FunctionArn",elem[0],"Deleted response",response,sep = "->")
                          - lambda_function_role_arn: !Ref LambdaFunctionRole
```

I am only currently tring to execute this with my root user account which has AdministratorAccess policy attached, however I get the following error:   What permissions/policies do I need to add?

````
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListFunctions operation: User: arn:aws:sts::148500871082:assumed-role/my-simple-lambda-function-stack-LambdaFunctionRole-1UD0AWLM5NBYP/my-simple-lambda-function-stack-LambdaFunction-4DFB3KPDMIUL is not authorized to perform: lambda:ListFunctions on resource: *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 8, in handler
    response = client.list_functions(FunctionVersion='ALL')
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)```
````

Comment: *"I am only currently tring to execute this with my root user account"* - no, you are not. Maybe you deploy this thing using that user, but the error message is pretty clear about which user is performing the operation: `assumed-role/my-simple-lambda-function-stack-LambdaFunctionRole-1UD0AWLM5NBYP/my-simple-lambda-function-stack-LambdaFunction-4DFB3KPDMIUL` which makes sense because the lambda only has the permission to do `logs:CreateLogGroup`, `logs:CreateLogStream` and `logs:PutLogEvents` but NOT `lambda:ListFunctions`

Comment: Note that the tutorial mentions *"You will need to create a Lambda with run time of Python and Role which has AWSLambdaFullAccess access policy attached."* which you do **not** do. You create a `AWSLambdaFullAccess` but that is very much different than attaching the pre-existing `AWSLambdaFullAccess` policy.

Comment: Insert the usual caveat about [continued use of the root user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html): "We strongly recommend that you do not use the root user for your everyday tasks, even the administrative ones."

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. I thought I was attaching a managed policy. I renamed the role to make it clear it is a created one, and I added the lambda:ListFunctions and it works as I had hoped. New to aws here, so thanks for the help.